# Double WEB-INF / META-INF folder JAVA

Tags: java, deployment, web-deployment

Hi I have found the folders META-INF and WEB-INF twice in my .war.

The first presence of the directories is in root folder:

META-INF
WEB-INF

The second presence is in WEB-INF\classes.

Is this a problem?
If yes how i can solve this?
Do I have to do something to my deployment assembly ?

Comment: What did you build the war with?

Comment: [SOLVED] i just change for error simple folder into source folder called WebContent

Comment: That's not the preferred solution, as those should reside in src/main/webapp, not in the default Eclipse folder WebContent.